# Android 10 - Storage Access Framework and get cursor data for uri with ContentResolver

Tags: android, uri, exists, storage-access-framework

With Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE I get this uri :

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/msd%3A126
```

I want create new folder under this uri, but first I want check it's existence, i do it with

```
resolver.query(uri, new String[] {
              DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE
            }, null, null, null);
```

with another application (file manager) I created manually 'abc' in root and I updated uri in my application

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/msd%3A126/document/msd%3A126%2Fabc
```

and passed it to query. While main uri returns data in cursor correctly, uri with subfolder gives error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For input string: "126/abc"
```

Has subfolder uri wrong path? Or why this error appears. 'abc' exists and cursor should contain data

Comment: Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` pointing at the tree. Then use `findFile()` to try looking for your child. "and I updated uri in my application" -- you cannot manually assemble document `Uri` values.

Comment: Thank you it works, but is there faster way? This is very slow

Comment: You are certainly welcome to look at the source code to `DocumentFile` and its related classes to see what it does [Here is the source to `1.0.1` of `DocumentFile`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/documentfile/documentfile/1.0.1-source/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile.java.html). `findFile()` calls `listFiles()`, then calls `getName()` for each element in that list. The repeated `getName()` calls probably are where the time is taken up.

Comment: Yes, I see it, that' why I tried it with resolver.query, I hoped I can do it this way...

Comment: `Thank you it works, but is there faster way? This is very slow` Indeed. DocumentFile is so slow. Better use DocumentsContract. It's 4 to 20 times as fast depending on the action. findFile() is very slow.

Comment: `resolver.query(uri,` What is the value of uri? Why dont you show where you got it from?